# Some precisions about the nuance of ちゃんと

Tags: nuances

**EDIT 1 :** For those interested by the subject, I've already asked a similar question about ちゃんと : [Meanings of ちゃんと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14988/meanings-of-%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8).

The sentence is from Dragon ball, the speaker just got robbed of the balls and says this :

> ドラゴンボールのことを知っているやつがいてもおかしくはないわね。昔の文献にちゃんと載ってるんだから...
>
> It's not surprising that some people know about the Dragonballs. With them being mentioned in old books and all...

I'm not sure what nuance ちゃんと brings in this context, I.E. what would be the difference in meaning or even in feeling (not necessarily in translation as I know it can be minimal or inexistant) if it wasn't there.

**EDIT 2 :** Ok, killing two birds with one stone here : some pages later, the same character responds to another one who is worried because they don't have a car anymore (which in this story can be transformed in small objects called Capsules to be transported).

> この前の町でちゃーーーーんとカプセルを買ったわよ!
>
> (No worries) I did buy some Capsules in the previous city!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @sova that the meaning is usually something like "properly" or "correctly."

I would say that in EDIT 1 the meaning is "clearly" - "... with them being so clearly mentioned ..."

I think that in EDIT 2 it also conveys a sense of "promptly" - "I returned the key promptly."

Answer (score 1):

ちゃんと is a beautiful word meaning "properly"

ちゃんとする or ちゃんとした usually means something like "with attention to all the details"

ちゃんと is often used to emphasize that someone "made sure" something was done correctly, or that something is legitimate.

鍵をちゃんとかえした
(かぎをちゃんとかえした)
I [made sure to have] returned the key.  This could also mean "I put the key back to its proper place."  It has a lot to do with doing things the "right" way which you'll learn more about as you delve into Japanese culture.  Great question.